# Why is it true that $f(x) \leq \frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b) + \frac{b-x}{b-a}f(a)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Why is the following true for convex functions: By convexity of a function $f(x)$, for $x \in [a,b]$ we have
$$
f(x) \leq \frac{x-a}{b-a}f(b) + \frac{b-x}{b-a}f(a)
$$
?

Comment: Would be great if you provide your thoughts too

Comment: What definition for a convex function are you using?

Comment: @Om3ga Why? Doesn't seem relevant here. Usually, I do, but for this, I think it would confuse me more if I tried to put it into words :)

Comment: @HansEngler I am not using anything specific - I am just reading another proof that includes this inequality and would like to know where it comes from.. A proof using any of the possible definitions would be fine!

Comment: You can't expect to prove anything without starting somewhere.

Comment: @HansEngler Indeed, but the time won't let me start from scratch and try to deduce it myself :)

Comment: Looks like we all tried to answer a live exam question here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like it was asked while the poster was in an exam.

Comment: @HansEngler Lol that was a rather random way of thinking... If you have to know, I came across the inequality when reading a proof in my lecture notes. People are not as malicious as you seem to think ;-)

Answer (score 2):

A real-valued function $f$ is convex provided that for all $x, y$ and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$,
$$
f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y).
$$
To see your claim, note that if $\lambda = \tfrac{b-x}{b-a}$, then
$\lambda \in [0, 1]$ (since $a \leq x \leq b$), and we also have
$$
\lambda a +(1-\lambda) b = \frac{a(b-x)}{b-a} + \frac{b(x-a)}{b-a} = x. 
$$
Therefore,
$$
f(x) = f(\lambda a +(1-\lambda) b) \leq \lambda f(a) + (1-\lambda) f(b)x = \frac{b-x}{b-a} f(a) + \frac{x-a}{b-a} f(b). 
$$
This is perhaps more clear written as follows:
$$
f(x) = f(a + \tfrac{x - a}{b-a}(b - a)) 
\leq f(a) + \tfrac{x-a}{b-a}\Big(f(b) - f(a)\Big).
$$
This gives the spirit of convexity: the function on the line segment $a$ to $b$ lies below the chord between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.